# How to Drop user from Netezza

Tags: netezza

How to drop user from netezza database?

I am trying to drop user name from netezza using below query

DROP USER 'mxy';

but it's giving me error like "You can't remove 'mxy' user because user contains objects"

'mxy' user create one user with his own schema object "mxy.jey'

How to remove user created object and as well 'mxy' user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User "mxy" have some table object like mxy.example table so i couldn't delete the mxy user from the Netezza database so i changed the table schema to system admin user account and now i am able to remove "mxy" user from Netezza database.